# layout_gravity does not appear on Intellisense

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to follow the tutorial to implement a navigation bar for my project, but whenever I type "layout_gravity" attribute into the XML file in the "android.support.design.widget.NavigationView" tag at "activity_main.xml" file, the IDE does not show me the "layout_gravity" attribute. For the record, I'm using Android Studio 3.2.1 on Windows 10.

In case anyone wondering, I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGEHMUBKjQ8

Here's my code:

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!--- include -->
        <include layout="@layout/navigation"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView

         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"

         **android:layout_gravity="start"**

         android:id="@+id/navigationView"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

> navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

> build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android 
{
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig 
  {
    applicationId "timmy.app.my.navigationAppLearning"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
          }
 } 

dependencies 
{
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0"
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="timmy.app.my.navigationAppLearning">

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you want to apply gravity to? May be try using constraintLayout inside Drawer Layout

Comment: where are you using layout_gravity

Comment: @Nudge Sorry, should have mentioned it. I already edit the question. Hopefully it's clear what my problem is.

Comment: @AliAhmed I've edited the question. Hopefully it's clearer now.

Comment: @TimBluesWin Try putting NavigationDrawer in ConstraintLayout and apply constraints on all side to make it appears in center

Comment: `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` doesn't have `layout_gravity` attribute

Comment: attributes are not universally applicable. It's very likely that the element in question does not support layout_gravity.

Comment: it's really wired . you done everything correct. did you tried by cleaning and rebuilding or restart studio

Answer (score 0):

```
    NavigationView is typically placed inside a DrawerLayout.

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
         android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

         <!-- Your contents -->

         <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
             android:id="@+id/navigation"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"
             android:layout_gravity="start"
             app:menu="@menu/my_navigation_items" />
     </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


Modify your code and put <NavigationView> inside <DrawerLayout>

Remove <LinearLayout> it will resolve your issue.

Hope it help you.
```